# Plotting a multivalued function

Tags: plotting

So I have a function

```
A *Sech[A *(x - c t)]* Exp[i*[(c/2) *x + (A^2 - c^2/4)* t]]
```

And I want to plot it but I'm not sure how. How do I specify each variable and plot it?

Consider A = 2, C= 4 for this case. I'd like to plot it between -4,4

Comment: Is it correct to assume that x and t are the variables and the rest are parameters?  
Is i a constant or the imaginary unit? Can you give the numerical values you want to assign to the various parameters?

Comment: x,t are indeed variables. Consider A = 2, C= 4 for this case. I'd like to plot it between -4,4

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can you please add these details to the OP so other users can read the proper description of the problem?

Comment: How about `A = 2; c = 4; ContourPlot[
 Re[A*Sech[A*(x - c *t)]*Exp[I*((c/2)*x + (A^2 - c^2/4)*t)]], {x, -4, 
  4}, {t, -4, 4}]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, first of all there are a couple of mistakes in the way you have written down the function. The proper way is given below:

```
fncn[x_, t_] := 
 A*Sech[A*(x - c t)]*Exp[I ((c/2)*x + (A^2 - c^2/4)*t)] // ExpToTrig //
   FullSimplify
```

You can ignore the `ExpToTrig` and `FullSimplify` and just check the differences in the square brackets and the parentheses.

Then we set up the constants

```
A = 2;
c = 4;
```

This is showing you the Real and Imaginary part of your function

```
{ContourPlot[Re@fncn[x, t], {x, -4, 4}, {t, -4, 4}, PlotPoints -> 50],
  ContourPlot[Im@fncn[x, t], {x, -4, 4}, {t, -4, 4}, 
  PlotRange -> {-4, 4}]}
```

And the following is giving you the absolute value of the function

```
Plot3D[Abs[fncn[x, t]], {x, -4, 4}, {t, -4, 4}]
```

Comment: That's great, exactly what I was after :)

Comment: Glad I was able to help!